# Facebook comment box display only website logo when user comment

Tags: facebook

I am using Facebook comment box in my website for commenting purpose on pictures, its working fine, i am also using a share button which is working fine too, but the problem is when its shared or users do commenting on the picture it is shared to their walls but a default website logo is shown there, i want to share the current picture on which user made comments or shared it ... I am posting it here because i couldnt find it on google or i was unable to make a query for google.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your link at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to see what thumbnails are pulled in by facebook when shared.

To configure which thumbnail to show when an URL from your site is shared you have to add this property to your html source in the header.

```
<meta property='og:image' content='url to First Image in your Page etc'/>
```

More details about meta tags for FB at [this link](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags).